# Display three dots in the end of a Tkinter Label text

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is there any way to show the three dots like ellipsis in CSS's text-overflow property?

This is a sample label:

```
Label(root, text = "This is some very long text!").pack()
```

[image]

And another one with a width property:

```
Label(root, text = "This is some very long text!", width = 15).pack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No builtin way, but you could easily make your own:

```
import tkinter as tk

class AyoubLabel(tk.Label):
    '''A type of Label that adds an ellipsis to overlong text'''
    def __init__(self, master=None, text=None, width=None, **kwargs):
        if text and width and len(text) > width:
            text = text[:width-3] + '...'
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, text=text, width=width, **kwargs)
```

Now just use `AyoubLabel` instead of `Label`.

This does not react to updating the Label after making it or using a textvariable, but you could add those abilities if you need them.

Comment: This solution will only work if the label size doesn't change when placed in the window with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. It assumes that the widget will be exactly the width specified. It also is a bit imprecise with variable width fonts. For example, if the width is 15, there is room for perhaps 20 or more characters if several are narrow( the lowercase i or l, commas, periods, etc). Though, quite often "good enough" is good enough.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is nothing built-in to tkinter to do that. You can get the same effect by binding to the `<Configure>` event, which fires whenever the widget changes size (such as when it's added to the window, or when the user resizes the window).

In the bound function you get get the font and the text, use the `measure` attribute of the font, and start chopping off characters until the label fits.

### Example

```
import Tkinter as tk           # py2
import tkFont                  # py2
#import tkinter as tk           # py3
#import tkinter.font as tkFont  # py3

root = tk.Tk()

def fitLabel(event):
    label = event.widget
    if not hasattr(label, "original_text"):
        # preserve the original text so we can restore
        # it if the widget grows.
        label.original_text = label.cget("text")

    font = tkFont.nametofont(label.cget("font"))
    text = label.original_text
    max_width = event.width
    actual_width = font.measure(text)
    if actual_width <= max_width:
        # the original text fits; no need to add ellipsis
        label.configure(text=text)
    else:
        # the original text won't fit. Keep shrinking
        # until it does
        while actual_width > max_width and len(text) > 1:
            text = text[:-1]
            actual_width = font.measure(text + "...")
        label.configure(text=text+"...")

label = tk.Label(root, text="This is some very long text!", width=15)
label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)
label.bind("<Configure>", fitLabel)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, this worked for me (unfortunately, Novel answered first)

Comment: doesn't work for me: the `nametofont()` method is raising this exception: TclError: named font TkTextFont does not already exist

Comment: @LRMAAX: with knowing more details I can't help. That's the name of a standard tkinter font, and has been for many years.

Comment: @BryanOakley I believe you, since I'm not typing the font name directly: it is being retrieved from a widget, which renders correctly, by the `cget()` method. The only difference is that I'm trying to apply this solution to a `ttk.Entry` instead of a `Label`.