# python Tkinter - How to count the quantity of characters can be shown in expanding Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some widgets on my Window. The Label lb3 expands with my window. I want to put there some number of characters from the long array. So, if the window is big there must be more chars, if it has been sized smaller, then less chars.
Therefore I need to know the current height and width of Label in chars.
There is an example for my problem:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import sys
import os    

last_event_H = 0
last_event_W = 0
LONG_ARRAY = ''

# when window sized
def sizing(event):
    global last_event_H
    global last_event_W
    global LONG_ARRAY
    if (event.width == last_event_W and event.height == last_event_H):
        return
    last_event_H = event.height
    last_event_W = event.width

    width_in_chars = lb3['width']
    height_in_chars = lb3['height']
    first_shown = int(lb1_text.get())
    lb3_text.set(LONG_ARRAY[first_shown:first_shown + width_in_chars * height_in_chars])
    lb2_text.set(LONG_ARRAY[first_shown + width_in_chars * height_in_chars] + ' ...')

class WrappingLabel(tk.Label):
    '''a type of Label that automatically adjusts the wrap to the size'''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.config(wraplength=self.winfo_width()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1280x640")
    dFont=tkFont.Font(family="Arial", size=30) # fixed Font
    LONG_ARRAY = 'a' * 100000 # of symbols

    tb_date = tk.Entry(root, font=dFont)
    tb_date.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)
    bt_find = tk.Button(root, text="...", font=dFont)
    bt_find.grid(column=9, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    lb1_text = tk.StringVar()
    lb1_text.set("1")
    lb1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lb1_text, width=10, font=dFont, anchor=tk.NW)
    lb1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    lb2_text = tk.StringVar()
    lb2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lb2_text, width=10, font=dFont, anchor=tk.NW)
    lb2.grid(column=1, row=10, columnspan=9, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    lb3_text = tk.StringVar()
    lb3 = WrappingLabel(root, textvariable=lb3_text, font=dFont, anchor=tk.NW, justify=tk.LEFT)
    lb3.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=9, rowspan=9, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    for x in range(11):
      tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, x, weight=1)
    for y in range(11):
      tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, y, weight=1)
    root.bind("<Configure>", sizing)

    width_in_chars = lb3['width']
    height_in_chars = lb3['height']
    print width_in_chars, height_in_chars # !!!!!!!!!!!!!
    print "-------"
    lb3_text.set(LONG_ARRAY[:width_in_chars * height_in_chars])
    lb2_text.set(LONG_ARRAY[width_in_chars * height_in_chars] + ' ...') # last shown character
    root.mainloop()
```

The width and height members of lb3 now are set to 0.
Because it is able to expand. Is there another way?

Comment: The `width` and `height` options are only going to reflect the values you configured the Label with, not the actual size of the widget.  The number of characters that will actually fit depends on *what those characters are*, anyway, unless you give it a monospaced font.  If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, I believe the solution would be to use a Text widget, set to `disabled` or `readonly` mode except when you're changing the contents - this will simply clip any text that doesn't fit, rather than resizing itself as a Label would.

Comment: It sounds like your question might actually be a duplicate of this: [Display three dots in the end of a Tkinter Label text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51143777/7432)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know exactly how many characters will fit, the first thing to do is get the size of the label. This needs to happen after the widget is displayed since it's width can't be known until that happens. You can do it beforehand by calling `winfo_reqwidth`, though that number might be larger or smaller than the actual width depending on the options you use for `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

Once you know the maximum size, you can use the `font_measure` method of a font object to compute the number of pixels in a string. It's then a simple matter of writing a loop that will figure out the maximum number of characters that will fit.

An example that shows how to dynamically add "..." for a label that is too long can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144251/7432

Answer (score 0):

Thank @BryanOakley for the helpful link

My version of solution the problem follows
(if someone could do it better, please, reply)

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import sys
import os
import bisect

LONG_ARRAY = ''

class KeyList(object):
    # bisect doesn't accept a key function, so we build the key into our sequence.
    def __init__(self, l, key):
        self.l = l
        self.key = key
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.key(self.l[index], index)

class WrappingLabel(tk.Label):
    '''a type of Label that automatically adjusts the wrap to the size'''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.fit)
        if (not hasattr(self, "original_text")):
            # preserve the original text so we can restore it if the widget grows.
            self.original_text = self["text"]
        self.font = tkFont.nametofont(self["font"])
        self.font_height = 48.88 # self.font.metrics('linespace')

    def fit(self, event):
        max_width = event.width
        max_height = event.height / self.font_height # rough n_lines
        text = LONG_ARRAY[:2000] # TODO !!! self.original_text
        actual_width = self.font.measure(text)
        if (actual_width  > max_width * max_height):
            # the original text won't fit. Keep shrinking until it does
            i = bisect.bisect_left(KeyList(text, key=lambda x,i: self.font.measure(text[:i]+ '...')), max_width * max_height)
            lb3_text.set(text[:i] + '...') # TODO !!! self.original_text
        return self.config(wraplength=self.winfo_width())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1280x640")
    dFont=tkFont.Font(family="Arial", size=30) # fixed Font
    LONG_ARRAY = 'a' * 100000 # of symbols

    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
    tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    tb_date = tk.Entry(frame, font=dFont)
    tb_date.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)
    bt_find = tk.Button(frame, text="...", font=dFont)
    bt_find.grid(column=9, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    lb1_text = tk.StringVar()
    lb1_text.set("1")
    lb1 = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=lb1_text, width=10, font=dFont, anchor=tk.NW)
    lb1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    lb3_text = tk.StringVar() 
    lb3 = WrappingLabel(frame, textvariable=lb3_text, font=dFont, anchor=tk.NW, justify=tk.LEFT)
    #lb3 = tk.Text(frame, font=dFont, state=tk.DISABLED, wrap=tk.CHAR) # bg=frame["bg"], fg='black', 
    lb3.grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=2, columnspan=9, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    lb2_text = tk.StringVar()
    lb2 = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=lb2_text, width=10, font=dFont, anchor=tk.NW)
    lb2.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=9, rowspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
    lb2_text.set('................................................')

    for y in range(11):
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
    for x in range(5):
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
    lb3_text.set(LONG_ARRAY[:2000])
    #lb3.insert(tk.INSERT, LONG_ARRAY[:2000])
    #lb3.insert(tk.END, "")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't a good general purpose solution since you're  hard-coding the font height. Why are you doing that? It also doesn't make sense that you're comparing the actual width to `max_width * max_height`. Since `event.height` could be twice as tall as the font, or half as tall, you'll likely get very unexpected results under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, for your comments. In my case the actual_width is the whole text width, because it is oneline and wraped by chars. Unfortunatelly I can't found the right way to calculate actual number of lines, so I just found the coefficient, that gives me the best filling of the tk.Text. I hope someone could improve it, if find out how.